# Using a shared library linked with other shared libs

Tags: c++, macos, linker, dylib, undefined-symbol

I've compiled on OSX a shared library with some external dependences (*boost*, *OpenGL*):

```
g++ -dynamiclib -undefined suppress -flat_namespace -o "libMY_LIB.dylib" ./windowbase.o -lGL -lGLU -lGLUT -lboost_system -lboost_thread
```

No errors, `file libMY_LIB.dylib` results in `Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64`, and `otool -L libMY_LIB.dylib` outputs:

```
libPixelsGL.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGL.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLU.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/GLUT.framework/Versions/A/GLUT (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
libboost_system.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
libboost_thread.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
/usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 52.0.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 159.1.0)
```

Now I try to link an executable against `libMY_LIB.dylib`, using only functions in `MY_LIB.h` (and compiled in the lib):

```
g++ -L"/path/to/MY_LIB" -o "Program" ./main.o -lMY_LIB
```

but it fails, printing:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"boost::system::system_category()", referenced from:
    __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)in main.o
    boost::mutex::mutex()in main.o
    boost::mutex::lock()    in main.o
    boost::mutex::unlock()    in main.o
"boost::system::generic_category()", referenced from:
    __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)in main.o
"boost::thread::detach()", referenced from:
    boost::thread::~thread()in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Some explanation and/or help?

Thanks!

## EDIT

I tried to link the lib without `-undefined suppress -flat_namespace` flags and the executable with them, and the latter worked. Could please anyone tell me why? May it be *boost* libs I have were compiled with those flags?

Renewed thanks!

Comment: Why're you compiling with `-undefined suppress -flat_namespace`?

Comment: Sincerely, because I've always seen them used. I've also tried to link without them, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most significant issue you have is that you're not linking your application against the libraries that provide the symbols that it uses.

Your error message calls out the `main.o` contains references to `boost::system::system_category()`, `boost::system::generic_category()`, and `boost::thread::detach()`. Therefore, when linking `main.o` in to an executable binary you need to link to a library that provides these symbols, in this case by passing `-lboost_system -lboost_thread`.

---

As for `-undefined suppress -flat_namespace`: these options have the effect of moving detection of missing symbols from build time to run time. In general you should avoid using these flags unless you have a very specific need. The reason that building your main executable with these flags "works" is that you've asked told the linker not to generate errors for missing symbols. Since it's ignorant of these symbols it does nothing to ensure that the library that provides them is loaded in to your application's address space at runtime. You're getting lucky since the symbols happen to be provided by libraries that your `libMY_LIB.dylib` also links to.

For sake of illustration, consider a simple test library, `liba.dylib`, that exports a function `a`:

```
$ cat a.c
int a(void)
{
    return 1;
}
$ cc -dynamiclib -o liba.dylib a.c
$
```

And a simple application that makes use of this function:

```
$ cat main.c
#include <stdio.h>

extern int a(void);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "a: %d\n", a());
    return 0;
}
```

Now let's look at three approaches to linking that library in to our application.

1) Without specifying the library at all

```
$ cc -o main main.c 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_a", referenced from:
      _main in main-JmKbTd.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This is the case you initially reported seeing in your question.

2) Specifying `-undefined suppress -flat_namespace`

```
$ cc -undefined suppress -flat_namespace -o main main.c 
$
```

That successfully created an executable, but when we run the binary:

```
$ ./main 
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _a
  Referenced from: /tmp/./main
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _a
  Referenced from: /tmp/./main
  Expected in: flat namespace

Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

In this case, the loader at runtime has no idea that it needs to load `liba.dylib` to find the function `a`:

```
$ otool -L main 
main:
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.0.0)
$ nm -m main | grep _a
                 (undefined) external _a
$
```

3) Specifying the library correctly

```
$ cc -L. -la -o main main.c 
$ ./main 
a: 1
$
```

And you can see that the binary `main` knows both to load `liba.dylib` and that it is `liba.dylib` that provides the function `a` that `main` uses:

```
$ otool -L main
main:
    liba.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.0.0)
$ nm -m main | grep _a
                 (undefined) external _a (from liba)
$
```

---

In summary, my recommendation is to stop passing `-undefined suppress -flat_namespace` at all when building your libraries and binaries, and to ensure that each component links to the necessary libraries for the symbols that it uses.

Comment: Well, thanks for your detailed answer.
What I want is the freedom to link my program without thinking about all the libs linked in `libMY_LIB.dylib`.
In the example above, in the main I'm using only functions available in MY_LIB, so that MY_LIB is correctly linked with the libs it's based on, without any further thinking about them (in the example `-lGL -lGLU -lGLUT -lboost_system -lboost_thread`).
Moreover, I've this problem only with _boost_ libs, not with _OpenGL_, which is correctly linked everywhere.

Comment: The problem is that you're _not_ only using symbols provided by you're library, you're also using symbols provided by boost. If you were using symbols provided only by your library then you'd only need to link to your library as you expect. The error message you provided mentions `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0`, which suggests that you have some static object that makes use of boost objects. Perhaps you're referencing boost from one of your library header files?

Comment: Uh, yeah, you're right! Not static, but two class members (`boost:thread` and `boost:mutex`).. A solution? I usually dislike using pointers at all, but it may be the case, or a declaration only in the source (which I also don't use often).

Comment: Sorry, I found I was wrong (the real project is big), and I declared a static mutex in a template header, so I just moved that (hiding it inside a compiled class) and everything went better. Thanks for your support!

Comment: Your answer helped me to understand much better how libraries are linked and how to debug them. Thank you for the clear and detailed explanation.